# How should I approach this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix. Let $v_1,v_2, \cdots ,v_k$ be linearly independent vectors
in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $\text{Ker}(A) = \{0\}$, then are the vectors $Av_1, Av_2, \cdots , Av_k$ necessarily linearly
independent?

My thoughts: I am stuck at how to approach this problem. I can only get that $Av_1, Av_2, \cdots, Av_k$ are non zero vectors since $\text{Ker}(A)=\{0\}.$ How should I continue?

Comment: Have you tried applying the definition of linear independence to the set of vectors in question?

Comment: I have edited your question, see if it's ok. For future reference, here is a tutorial for [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that they weren't linearly independent. Then 
$$Av_1 + Av_2 + ... + Av_k = 0$$
Implying
$$A(v_1 + v_2 + ... + v_k) =0$$
By assumption $(v_1 + v_2 + ... + v_k) $ cannot be zero. So we have that $A \vec{v} =0$ for some $\vec{v} \neq 0,$ a contradiction.

Comment: I was the original poster, but I don't have an account here. I can't edit my comment, but you actually have to consider the arbitrary linear combination
$$c_1 A v_1 + c_2 A v_2 + ... + c_k A v_k=0$$
$$A(c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + ... + c_k v_k)=0$$

Comment: Better like this: Suppose that 
 $$c_1Av_1 + c_2Av_2 + ... + c_kAv_k = 0$$
 for some constants $c_1,\dots,c_k$. Then
 $$A(c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + ... + c_kv_k) =0$$
 By assumption, $\ker A=0$, so $c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + ... + c_kv_k=0$. But $v_1,\dots,v_k$ are linearly independent, so $c_1=\dots=c_k=0$.  So, $Av_1,\dots,Av_k$ are linearly independent.